# Multiple AND/OR option with Full text Boolean search

Tags: php, mysql, boolean, full-text-search

I need a query for searching the keyword with Multiple AND/OR option. That field is tagged as Full text in mysql.

First keyword will be  : `"Keyword1",` Second one is `"Keyword2"` and the third one `"Keyword3"`.

I need to include all the keywords as in via single text box. So i will send as like `"Keyword1" AND "Keyword" AND "Keyword"`. In this case we need to get the results based on all keywords.
Some other cases,

```
1) "Keyword1" AND "Keyword2" OR "Keyword3" 
2) "Keyword1" OR "Keyword2" AND "Keyword3"
3) "Keyword1" AND "Keyword2" NOT "Keyword3"
4) "Keyword1" NOT "Keyword2"
```

This may be 3 keywords or 2 keywords.

I am using the below query for single keyword search. First i will get the value in `PHP` variable then i will pass this to mysql.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE MATCH (pd_description, pd_awards, pd_experience, pd_qualification) AGAINST ('keyword1' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I tried below method to find the solution, but it is working for 2 keywords only.

```
if (strpos($search_text,' AND ') !== false) {
      $explode_keyword      = explode(' AND ',$search_text);
      $keyword_left         = $explode_keyword[0];
      $keyword_right        = $explode_keyword[1]; 
      $string_match         = '"'.$keyword_left.'"';
      $string_match_right         = '"'.$keyword_right.'"';
}
```

Mysql query i am used,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE MATCH (pd_description, pd_awards, pd_experience, pd_qualification) AGAINST ('".$string_match."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND MATCH (pd_description, pd_awards, pd_experience, pd_qualification) AGAINST ('".$string_match_right."' IN BOOLEAN MODE).
```

Same method i used for '`OR`'. But it doesn't work for multiple words. 
So i need get the results based on all cases that i mentioned. Please someone help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MySQL 5.5 Manual, you will use the + for AND, the - for NOT and OR does not get an operator. It has an excellent example if you check out the link below.

[MySQL 5.5 Manual-Boolean Full Text Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)